# Less css absolute path not displaying properly

Tags: php, css, less

The problem is that i set a variable with the absolute path to an image, but when I replace the variable with the value in my .less file, it's not displayed properly.

```
$mediaUrl = explode('://',Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA));
$lessClass->setVariables(array('BASE_URL_MEDIA' => $mediaUrl[1]));
// $mediaUrl[1] = 'mysite.domain.com/media/ and if I check $lessClass the variable is set properly
try {
    return $lessClass->compileFile($filePath);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return '';
}
```

I've been struggling for hours to figure it out why the output is this after I compile

```
.main-container {background-image:~"url('http://@{BASE_URL_MEDIA}someDir/anotherDir/')";}
// returns url('http://mysitesomeDir/anotherDir/'
```

It loads the string till the first "."
Can someone please help me?

Note: If I write the path in my .less file, it is displayed as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem. 
Looking through the [documentation](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#compiling) I found that I was missing some apostrophes.

```
 $mediaUrl = "'" . Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . "'";
    $lessClass->setVariables(array('BASE_URL_MEDIA' => $mediaUrl));
```

And in my .less file

```
.main-container {background-image: url("@{BASE_URL_MEDIA}someDir/anotherDir/@{MY_FILE}");}
```

I hope this will help others.